# Using php server to respond to http requests from Android

Tags: php, android

I did some web programming and used php server to respond to http requests to return a web page. Now I need that a server responds to http request send from Android device, just be retrieving data. I also wrote some simple servers myself in C# and Java, using sockets, but I'm confused how to do that using php scripts?

So I would like to respond to http request by sending data from a database, how to do that?

If you can recommend some tutorials that would be also great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommand these tutorials

1. [How to Execute HTTP POST Requests in Android](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android)
2. [connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
3. [Executing a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good tutorial.

- [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Both of your recommendations are good, but Prag's gave that one and two more, so I accepted his answer and gave you +1. Thanks :)